# UWP NavigationView.PaneFooter Rollover Issues

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Got an issue with the way the PaneFooter is handling rollover effects for Navigation Menu Items.

Heres the Bug
[image]

As you can see, the ChangeUser button is cutting off the rollover effect prematurely leading to an odd looking highlight.

I was wondering if anyones come across this or knows a fix?

Heres my projects current XAML for the Nav View

```
<Page
    x:Class="BS.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BS"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    RequestedTheme="Dark"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>

    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
                          BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                          TintColor="#262626"
                          TintOpacity="0.825"
                          FallbackColor="#262626"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <NavigationView IsSettingsVisible="False" x:Name="NavView" PaneTitle="Budget Sheet" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal" Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDarkBackground}">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Page2" Margin="0, 2, 1, 0" Tag="New_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <AppBarButton Icon="OpenFile" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Open_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Save_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Sheet" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>                
                <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="HomeItem" Content="HOME" Tag="HOME_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#b880fc"/>
                <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="OverviewItem" Content="OVERVIEW" Tag="OverView_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#b880fc"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="BItem" Content="B" Tag="B_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#b880fc"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="PItem" Content="P" Tag="BP_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#b880fc"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="TItem" Content="T" Tag="T_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#b880fc"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="PDItem" Content="PD" Tag="PD_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#b880fc"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
                <StackPanel>
                    <NavigationViewItem Style="{ThemeResource NavigationViewTitleHeaderContentControlTextStyle}" Name="ChangePerson" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Change User" Icon="Contact" Tag="UserChange_Page" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#b880fc"/>
                </StackPanel>                                 
            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your footer control is nested inside a StackPanel, which is adding extra padding to it and hence making it look odd. You have following solutions:

1. remove **Stackpanel** and add **NavigationViewItem** directly to the footer and set **HorizontalAlignment** of your footer NavigationViewItem to Stretch.
2. keep the stackpanel the way it is and just change the **HorizontalAlignment** of your footer navigationViewitem to **Stretch**
3. best solution in my opinion would be to use the new **NavigationView** provided in the new preview release of **winui** library, you can use it through **nuget** and all of its controls have backwards compatibility until **Anniversary update** for windows 10, so it will solve more problems for your app as well. learn more here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/

### Update

Here is a blog post for further details about **WinUi** https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/07/23/windows-ui-library-preview-released/

**winui** is actually a nuget library which can be used in your uwp app. and as mentioned in the blog above, you can visit the dev branch of xamlUI samples repo on Github to see how new **NavigationView** is implemented, I am sure that will solve your needs, and if it still doesn't you can link this Stack Overflow question and open an issue in that repo and I am sure the team will help you.

Comment: Hi, I dont mean to sound stupid. I believe i have already updated to the mentioned edition of the NavigationView. Im running build 17723 currently as my target version and Min version and im still bumping into these issues. Im not sure if ive done anything wrong but ive downloaded and installed the mentioned MUX controls in the documentation for WinUI

Comment: did u try the 1st to options I suggested?

Comment: I think u misunderstood the point about "winui" see the updated answer please

Comment: I tried the first option and still the same issue. Ive looked into using the WinUI and downloaded all the NuGet Packages and still the same issue. Just seems to be an issue with the footer Everything else is fine :/

Comment: you dont need to download the nuget packages u have to add the nuget pakages in your project references and then you have to use the new control within ur app after using the winui namespace, have u never used a nuget package for xaml ui before? that is why I suggested you should see the samples ( link in blog post ) to understand how exactly you can use that control.

Comment: Ive never used a NuGet before no. Ive only just started using UWP/XAML within the past week so still in the learning process. Ive added a reference which now works so i can see mux:NavigationView stuff. Ive been unable to adjust the NavigationViewItem though so the rollover highlight is correct. It seems as though it may be a limitation of the footer. Im using a StackPanel & TextBlocks now.

Comment: thats ok you will learn this way, and yeah mux:NavigationView, this is how you are supposed to use the control from winui. I bet there might be a <NavigationView.footer> property on this navigation view. also I think the best way tofind help for this new control is to open an issue on github repo where the samples are, do you know how to do tht?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178208/discussion-between-batteredburrito-and-touseefbsb).